# the composition of Baire one with a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that if $f$ is Baire one then for any continuous function $g$, $g \circ f$ is a Baire one function.

I am curious with the converse. Is there a non Baire one function such that for any continuous function $g$, $g \circ f$ is a Baire one function?

Comment: you mean for some $g$, in general this can not be true since $g=Id$ would not work.

Comment: @user3808066,  why it would not work for $g =Id$?

Comment: Assume $f$ is not Baire one then $Id\circ f=f$ is still not Baire one.

Comment: @user3808066, a identity mapping is not always continuous

Comment: What is your definition of Baire one functions? The one I know is for functions from a topological space to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and in this case $g$ has to go from $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself with the same topology.

Comment: @user3808066, I defined a Baire one function $f$ from a complete separable metric space $(X, d_x)$ to a complete separable metric space $(Y, d_y)$ and $g$ is a continuous function from a metric space $(Y, d_y)$ to  a metric space $(Z, d_z)$. The identity mapping $Id: Y \to Z$ is continuous iff $d_z$ open is $d_y$ open.

Comment: ok, however in that case $Id$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding there are two cases, either we have metric spaces $X,Y,Z$ fixed and $f:X\to T$ such that for all $g$ continuous $f\circ g$ is Baire one. In this case a counterexample would be to take any $X,Y$ with a non Baire $f:X\to Y$ then taking $Z=\{0\}$  it follows that $g\circ f$ is Baire one for all $g:Y\to Z$.

The second case is $X,Y$ are fixed and so is $f:X\to Y$ and for all metric spaces $Z$ and all continuous $g:Y\to Z$, $g\circ f$ is Baire one. In this case one can take $Z=Y$ and $g=Id_Y$ and hence $g\circ f = f$ is Baire one.